# How to handle Translation in twig file using variables?

Tags: symfony, translation, twig, code-translation, bundles

I have a twig file and a yml, in which I define the variables for translation

e.g.:

**YML File -**
`variable.for.translation: Disponible, para tí`

**Content of Twig File -**

```
<h2>"Hola, Follow {{ variableName }} en Twitter</h2>
```

I wanted to make a variable for

```
Hola, Follow {{ variableName }} en Twitter
```

in translation file (i.e my yml file).
Currently i am doing it like this :
In YML -

```
follow.us.twitter: Hola, Follow 

follow.us.twitter1: en Twitter
```

In Twig -

```
<h2>{{ "follow.us.twitter"|trans([], "workend") }} {{ variableName }} {{ "follow.us.twitter1"|trans([], "workend") }}</h2>
```

Its working fine, but the problem is that i now have 3 variables in a twig which are too much :

```
 1. follow.us.twitter
 2. follow.us.twitter1
 3. {{ variableName }}
```

I tried to do it with a single variable, like so:

```
follow.us.in.twitter : Hola, Follow {{ variableName }} en Twitter 
and  
<h2>{{ "follow.us.in.twitter"|trans([], "workend") }}</h2>
```

but it didn't work. The problem is *the variable i.e {{ variableName }}* I am using.

Is there any way to do handle a predefined variable and define it in translation file?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You were going on right track, what you missed is just to pass `someVariable` as a **parameter** to trans() in your **Twig file** as:

```
<h2>{{ "follow.us.in.twitter"|trans({'%someVariable%': someVariable}, "workend") }}</h2>
```

Now your message in **Yml file** should be as:

```
follow.us.in.twitter: Hola, Follow %someVariable% en Twitter
```

This should work.
For more details and clarity you can refer the following:
[Symfony Book](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html)

Good Luck.

Comment: If I pass many arguments to twig, can't Twig just use the whole array without defining them to trans? So if I have:
`{{ reminder.Email|trans({'%firstName%' : firstName, '%lastName%' : lastName, '%siteUrl%' : siteUrl}) }}`

why can't just map a whole array, that will be used to replace %var% with var?

Comment: Will be better if this is replaced by this..
{'%variableName%': variableName} ===> {'%variableName%': variableValue}