# How to pass the variable in translation.en.yml

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am using translation.en.yml in twig.

What I want to do is very simple ,please check the code below.

in my twig

```
{{ "message.thxContactUs" | trans({'%username%' : "myName"})}}
```

in my translation.en.yml

```
message: 
    thxContactUs: Dear {{username}} thank you for contacting us
```

however this out put is

```
Dear {{username}} thank you for contacting us
```

however it doesn't work, please could anyone correct this code??

Comment: The way you pass your variable from twig should match in your translation file as well. Change `{{username}}` with `%username%`

Comment: Thanks your comment slove my problem

Comment: Keep in mind that using `% ... %` is just a convention. It's followed by most Symfony developers and it's recommended to use that format, but if you don't like it, you can change it. In your example, you could use `{{ "message.thxContactUs" | trans({'{{username}}' : "myName"}) }}` and it should work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks I will obey the standard way though, it is good knowledge for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to type the variable in yml on this way:

```
message: 
    thxContactUs: Dear %username% thank you for contacting us
```

Check this question:

[How to handle Translation in twig file using variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726636/how-to-handle-translation-in-twig-file-using-variables)